# Add joint owner to title of a fully paid house in the United States

Tags: united-states, home-ownership, title

While married, I bought a property, in my name only, nine years ago.

It has been fully paid off for six years.

I want to add my spouse of 20 years as a joint owner on the title.

What is the process for doing this?

**Update:** 
I spoke to the original title company, and they will submit a Warranty Deed and will record with the county for $100 including recording fees.

Comment: What country/state are you in?

Comment: I understand exactly why you're doing this, but -- as someone who just went through a divorce -- must warn you to think clearly and cold-heartedly about it.

Comment: @DJClayworth, the property is in Utah

Comment: @RonJohn, yeah man, I get you. Sorry you had to deal with it.. We have been married for 20 year, hopefully it stays that way..

Comment: I am not familiar with Utah law, but it's also possible that adding your spouse to the title doesn't actually change her interest in the house, but rather will just make things simpler in the event of the OP's death.

Comment: "We have been married for 20 year".  Ok; I thought you were recently married, and doing this on emotion.  Following up on the @chepner comment:  **How long ago** did you buy the house, and **how long ago** did you paid off?  Because even though Utah is not a community property state, the judge might consider her to have a half stake in it anyway.

Comment: @RonJohn, almost 9 years ago, her credit rating was affecting the rate, so did not add her to the title. Paid off 6 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

You go to a lawyer and tell them what you want to do.

You need a lawyer because you want to make sure a transaction like this is watertight. Lawyers know exactly the right way to do this In your jurisdiction.

Comment: Yes, see a lawyer. If you want to educate yourself first, try here; https://athenapaquette.com/5-things-know-adding-new-spouse-title/

Comment: @Mattman944 flesh this out and make it into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

File a "quitclaim" deed with the county. Go to your county's website or call the county to get the form. It basically transfers ownership from person or persons to another person or persons. They can probably give you the legal description and notarize the form as well.

You might also call a local title company and see if they can offer any suggestions.

Comment: D Stanley, we actually did talk to a title company and they said they would do it. Just that the fee is enormous, 200 bucks.

Comment: You're basically paying for an hour or two of their time. A lawyer would be even more expensive. I understand the concern from the other answer but if you know the risks then the mechanics aren't that hard. That said, there can be serious ramifications if you get it wrong, so it may be worth the cost of someone's expertise.

Comment: 200 dollars to transfer ownership of a house doesn't seem like an "enormous" fee.

Comment: @xyious, I would agree wholeheartedly. user1807337, Have you seen how much paperwork is necessary to document this all correctly? $200 seems like a bargain to have some experts do that for you...

Comment: Yeah.. I will just get it done with the title company..